# Azure Data Factory - AWS Oracle Database to Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to connect ADF to an Oracle database on AWS as source and migrate data to an Azure SQL Server?

I've made some attempties and the result was always timeout.

The goal was achieved using an Integration Runtime, but didn't wanted to use it. I'd like a direct connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've made some attempties and the result was always timeout.

Hi,Vinicius. Based on the [Oracle connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle),no more special properties you need to configure except host,user,password properties etc for Oracle database on AWS. You could check the [supported versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle#supported-capabilities) of an Oracle database.

If you still have timeout issue, you could commit [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) to azure data factory to find an official statement.

Since you want to avoid IR, maybe you could refer to below solutions:

1.Try export data to `AWS S3` and ADF supports [AWS S3 connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-simple-storage-service) as source.

2.Try to use [Data Integration - Kettle](https://community.hitachivantara.com/docs/DOC-1009855-data-integration-kettle) tool to transfer data by jdbc driver.

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
Just for the records, I've contacted MS and they said that they treat Oracle as an "On Premise" DB, and all on premise DB needs a Self Hosted IR.